# IIS Url Rewrite Module and Dynamic Compression

Tags: asp.net, compression, url-rewrite-module

I have some problem with using rewrite module. I have an exception when trying to use Dynamic Compression. So to fix it by disabling this feature in "web.config" file:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
```

But what if I heed this feature to be enabled? Is there any way to use Rewrite Module and Dynamic Compression together?

Comment: Could you paste error message?

Comment: Here is the screen: http://i.imgur.com/uC3Zs.png

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about OUTBOUND rewrites, you *can*, but I personally never had any joy with it. Check out this post [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1165899.aspx)

It is something to do with the fact outbound rewrites can only be done to uncompressed responses, but if you look at the thread above, there are some fiddly work arounds.

You CAN have static compression enabled though!

Comment: There is another problem: I don't think that my hosting provider will allow me to change registry keys.

Comment: Yea that's the main problem with that 'work around'. I just stuck with using static compression in the end. For the content I was serving, dynamic probably wouldn't have saved me much anyway.

Comment: I had problems with all three (dynamic, static and dynamic before Cache.  I had to turn them all off.